# (Jersy) How to write Get method without parameters

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I want to write following GET method without a QueryParam

Ideally it should return all the records.

```
 @GET
 @Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON } )
 Response getAircraft( @Context SecurityContext aSc, @QueryParam( ID_PARAM ) String aAircraftId );
```

Any Idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Why not just remove `QueryParam`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the QueryParam and the variable so it looks like this:

```
@GET
@Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON } )
Response getAircraft( @Context SecurityContext aSc) {
//return something
}
```

The Jersey Documentation is pretty good so you can find most of the stuff you need there: https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html